# Mrjob Step is failing. How do debug?

Tags: python, amazon-emr, mrjob, common-crawl

I am trying to run sample `mrjob` in EMR cluster. I have created EMR cluster manually in AWS dashboard and started mrjob as follows

```
python keywords.py -r emr s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2018-34/wet.paths.gz --cluster-id j-22GFG1FUGS12L
```

Job is getting failed with following error message

```
Using configs in /etc/mrjob.conf
Using s3://mrjob-07d6e1cbb9127021/tmp/ as our temp dir on S3
emr_api_params is deprecated and does nothing. Please use extra_cluster_params instead
Could not infer endpoint for bucket commoncrawl; assuming defaults
Copying local files to s3://mrjob-07d6e1cbb9127021/tmp/keywords.ec2-user.20181002.164319.430013/files/...
Adding our job to existing cluster j-22GFG1FUGS12L
Creating temp directory /tmp/phonenumers.ec2-user.20181002.164319.430013
Connect to resource manager at: http://localhost:40750/cluster
Waiting for Step 1 of 1 (s-2OZF2A4TZTS06) to complete...
  RUNNING for 0:00:18
  FAILED
Cluster j-22GFG1FUGS12L is WAITING: Cluster ready after last step failed.
Attempting to fetch counters from logs...
Waiting 10 minutes for logs to transfer to S3... (ctrl-c to skip)
```

How do I see the failure messages?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [EMR docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html) how to get the job and task logs. Because digging into the cluster logs isn't trivial I would recommend to test the Python code exhaustively using [mrjob's local runner](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/runners.html#testing-locally).

Comment: Thanks. I will check. I could not run the mrjob locally with S3 (using boto python library). Do you have any idea?